# How to stop a loop with keyboard.add_hotkey, while this loop is started by keyboard.add_hotkey?

Tags: python

The following code works perfectly, the loop can be stop by pressing esc:

```
import time
import keyboard

run = 1

def end():
    global run
    run = 0
    print(run)

def do_stuff():
    while run:
        print('running')
        time.sleep(0.5)

keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', end)
do_stuff()
```

But if I start this loop with another add_hotkey, I cannot stop it with esc anymore.

```
import time
import keyboard

run = 1

def end():
    global run
    run = 0
    print(run)

def do_stuff():
    while run:
        print('running')
        time.sleep(0.5)

keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', end)
# do_stuff()

keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', do_stuff)
keyboard.wait()
```

What should I do to stop this loop? I tried to replace the `while run:` with `while not keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):`. It can stop the loop if I hold the esc for a while. But it doesn't seem like a good solution.

=======================
updates:
the following works:

```
import keyboard
import threading

run = 1

def end():
    global run
    run = 0
    print(run)

def do_stuff():
    while run:
        print('running')
        time.sleep(0.5)

def new_do_stuff():
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, name='LoopThread')
    t.start()


keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', end)
keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', new_do_stuff)
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the second example you enter the `do_stuff()` loop through the hotkey and never leave the `do_stuff()` loop, the system is still captured in the hotkey command and is not listening for hotkeys anymore. You would have to find a way to leave the loop after the `keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', do_stuff)` command and enter it externally through another way, so the system listens for hotkey-entries again.

I'm not aware of the context you're using this in, but using some sort of a main-loop, that does nothing but wait for a flag to be set (it should be set when you get the hotkey interrupt) and then enters the `do_stuff()` loop seems like a way to solve it.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it by running the loop in a new thread.